# Mapstruct how to handle mapping nested objects wrapped in JsonNullable?

Tags: mapstruct

I realize this might be pushing mapStruct beyond what it was made for, but in case I am missing something...

I have an openapi-generator generated set of nested objects that are all wrapped in JsonNullable for a `PATCH` endpoint (without the wrapping, java can't distinguish between json properties explicitly set to `null` and properties that were not defined since they both map to java's `null`). I have to map those objects back and forth between the openapi-generated java objects and JPA entities, and some of the structures between the openapi-generated objects and the JPA entities are not symmetric.

I used dot-notation in `source` and `target` to handle the non-symmetric mapping and that worked great until everything got wrapped in JsonNullable. I can't figure out how to combine the nesting and the wrapping in one `@Mapping`. Googled a lot and scoured github issues. Tried breaking it apart into multiple mapping methods but not making progress that way either. Considered custom mappings but it is looking way too complicated to maintain.

Example of the sort of thing I am trying to do:

```
// My open-api-generator generated objects
class Thing {
    JsonNullable<Thing2> thing2;
}

class Thing2 {
    JsonNullable<Thing3> thing3
}

class Thing3 {
    JsonNullable<String> myString;
}

---

class MyEntity {
    String whereMyStringShouldGetMappedFrom;
}

---

class MyMapper {
    @Mapping(source="whereMyStringShouldGetMappedFrom", target="thing.thing2.thing3") // <---- this doesn't work because each property is wrapped in JsonNullable
    public abstract TopLevelThing mapIt(MyEntity myentity);
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help. a bit awkward, but it works for me.
works well with modelmapper as well

```
@Column(name="string_column",nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
String myString;
public JsonNullable<String> getMyString(){
    return myString == null ? null : JsonNullable.of(myString);
}
public void setMyString(JsonNullable<String> arg){
    this.myString = arg == null ? null : arg.orElse(null);
}
```

another option is to use this, depending on what you want to display in the result, and how you choose to implement your service, etc:

```
@Column(name = "string_column", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = true)
@Setter
Boolean myString;
public JsonNullable<String> getMyString() {
    return JsonNullable.of(myString);
}
```

Comment: What does this answer have to do with MapStruct?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom converter for those cases like this:

```
final Converter<String, JsonNullable<String>> stringJsonNullableConverter = new AbstractConverter<>() {
    @Override
    protected JsonNullable<String> convert(final String source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return JsonNullable.of(source);
    }
};

modelMapper.addConverter(stringJsonNullableConverter);
```

That way, everytime it needs to map a String to a JsonNullable, your converter will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide custom mapping methods to map to/from JsonNullable.

```
public <Z> Z convertNullable(JsonNullable<Z> source) {
    return source.get();
}

public <Z> JsonNullable<Z> convertNullable(Z source) {
    if (source == null) {
        return JsonNullable.undefined();
    }

    return JsonNullable.of(source);
}
```

And a conditional mapping to only apply the mapping when the JsonNullable is present.

```
@Condition
public boolean shouldMapNullable(JsonNullable<?> source) {
    return source.isPresent();
}
```